# Is it possible to host an Eclipse plugin repository locally behind a proxy?

Tags: eclipse

Using Eclipse behind a Windows proxy causes a lot of difficulty downloading and updating plugins, even with something like CNTLM as a proxy.

**Is it possible to have something like a Nexus repository for hosting Eclipse Plugins on the local network?**

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse uses the [Equinox p2](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/rt.equinox.p2) repository to manage executables, configuration and dependency resolution. Equinox p2 is described is this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/irbull/p2-introduction)

To directly answer the question above [Jfrog's Artifactory Pro](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/P2+Repositories) supports proxying and caching of P2 repositories.

*Its important to note the free version does not support this functionality.*